# WHERE clause in CASE

Tags: sql

I want to write SQL that if field **@tank_id** is null then not include this field in WHERE clause. Else include.

So here my sql:

```
DECLARE @dateTo AS DATE = '01.01.2018'    
DECLARE @tank_Id int = null
SELECT sum(field_1 - field_2) FROM myTable
(CASE 
    WHEN @tank_id = 0 THEN (WHERE dt < @dateTo)
    ELSE (WHERE dt < @dateTo AND tank_id = @tank_id)
END)
```

But I get error:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
SQLState:  S1000
ErrorCode: 156
```

Comment: `WHERE dt < @dateTo AND tank_id IN (0,@tank_id)`

Comment: Same error. Not help

Comment: Replace the `case` statement with the above `where` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try the following

```
DECLARE @dateTo AS DATE = '01.01.2018'
DECLARE @tank_Id int = null
SELECT sum(field_1 - field_2) 
FROM myTable
WHERE dt < @dateTo
AND tank_id = (
case when @tank_id is null then tank_id else @tank_id end
)
```

Comment: Please note that this will not return records where `tank_id` is null.

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided does not match your text description. 
In your description, you are asking how to not use the `@tank_id` if it's `null`, but in the code it looks like you want to not use it if it's `0` - so I'm going on the assumption that the text of the question is correct.

You can't use `case` as a flow control.
`case` is an expression that can only be used to return a single scalar value based on condition(s).
However, for this kind of query you don't need to use `case`, you can simply use a combination of `and` and `or`, like the following:

```
DECLARE @dateTo AS DATE = '01.01.2018'    
DECLARE @tank_Id int = null
SELECT sum(field_1 - field_2) 
FROM myTable
WHERE dt < @dateTo
AND (
    tank_id = @tank_id
    OR @tank_id IS NULL 
)
```

BTW, you should always specify the RDBMS you are working with (oracle, mySql, postgreSQL, SQL Server etc`) in the tags, as well as add a tag for the specific version.

Answer (score 1):

No can do that.

A SELECT can be accompanied by at most one WHERE.  That's how the syntax is *defined*.

That WHERE clause, if present, gets *compiled* (a.o. for the purpose of determining the physical data access strategy) so there is simply no means to make "what the WHERE clause consists of" in any way dependent upon information that can be known only at run-time (e.g. values in columns of the rows being processed).

So what you have to do is think about the cases you can run into and write your *single* WHERE clause such that it covers all cases.  The comments and answers show you the correct way for the particular case you mentioned in your question.